# Getting multiple records that are inserted in a table

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hi all I would like to get all the Id's that are newly inserted. Actually I am inserting the data in to a table based on foreign key id.

```
Insert into table()
Values(SELECT * FROM table where fId=X)
```

Here the two tables are same, so after inserting the data I would like to return all the Identities that got inserterd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `OUTPUT` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause in your insert. Here's a working example:

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), txt VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @tmp (txt)
OUTPUT INSERTED.id
VALUES ('a'),('b')
```

So for your query - **which is not a valid insert statement** - it would be:

```
Insert into table()
OUTPUT INSERTED.id_column_you_need_to_be_returned
Values(SELECT * FROM table where fId=X)
```